# rc.conf error causing read-only boot, FreeBSD

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, read-only, unmounting

I recently edited my `/etc/rc.conf` and believe there to be a syntax error.
When I try to boot I receive an error message in regards to the file and then it boots and mounts the file-system in read only mode so even as root I cannot edit that file.

Would unmounting the root filesystem and then remounting as read/write be feasible?

Answer (score 3):

`mount -uw /`

will remount the root filesystem read/write.

Comment: # mount -a # after will mount other partitions and # su - will make environment right

Comment: … and `zfs mount -a`